# Several templates for different tasks

Tags: templates, symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to get two different layout for a typical authorization, registration, and to display in the popup window.

A good example of Facebook http://www.facebook.com/login.php?display=popup and http://www.facebook.com/login.php

But, in my case was called link /oauth/v2/auth and Security automatically redirects to the login page.

My security.yml:

```
    oauth_token:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
        security:   false

    oauth_authorize:
        pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
        anonymous: true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            failure_forward: true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use [twig include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) for the login form.

You can then have as many views as you like with the login form on?